# Guilds Highest Role Command?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to get the highest role in the guild with discord.js

```
message.guild.roles.highestRole
```

This doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks from now :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the list is sorted from highest to lowest, so you can get the first element of the list of roles

Comment: This Questions still seems to be unresolved, could you please mark a Answer as accepted, or self answer if you have found the Solution? @IronStar Games

Answer (score 2):

- For discord.js v12 / master use [`message.guild.roles.highest.name`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/RoleStore?scrollTo=highest)
- For discord.js v11.4.x / stable use [`message.guild.roles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=roles)[`.sort((b, a) => a.position - b.position || a.id - b.id)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=sort)[`.first()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=first)[`.name`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=name), this will sort the roles Collection by their position and then get the highest one, and return the name of it.

Comment: sorry but it didnt work thanks anyway. Do you know another way ?? Thanks from now :)

Comment: Any error ? More info on how it did not work please.

Comment: Undefined `name` error. I made an else if statement like this:

`if(message.guild.roles.find('name', 'VIP') == message.guild.roles.highest.name) return message.reply('OK');`

Comment: @IronStarGames You forgot to add the `.name` to the "VIP" role you're finding: `if (message.guild.roles.find('name', 'VIP').name == message.guild.roles.highest.name) return message.reply('OK');`

Comment: @FedericoGrandi Still getting undefined `name`

Comment: `.find()` returns a Promise, wait for it using `await` or attaching a `.then()` and the rest of your code inside of it.

Comment: @slothiful That's not true: the [`Collection.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) does not return any Promise

Comment: @IronStarGames 1) Are you sure you're using the right version of discord.js? I saw that you tried only one of the two options you were given. 2) What is the 'undefined name' error? Is it just your way to say that `.name` is undefined or are you getting an error that says something like "can't find property 'name' of undefined"?

Comment: @FedericoGrandi No idea what I was thinking of, you're right.

Comment: @FedericoGrandi The new error is : `Cannot read property 'name' of null` Thanks from now.

Comment: @IronStarGames what about the first thing I asked you: have you checked your version of Discord.js?

Comment: Hey the 2nd method that should work with all versions