# Check if user and bot role is higher than the mentioned user (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a set nickname command and here is my code:

```
if (message.mentions.members.first().roles.highest.position > bot.user.roles.highest.position) return message.channel.send("My highest role is lower than the mentioned user's role");
```

But that code there is an error: `Type error: Cannot read property of "highest" of undefined`

I also tried this:

```
if (message.mentions.members.first().roles.highest.comparePositionTo(bot.user.roles.highest) > 0) {
    return message.channel.send("Your highest role is lower than the mentioned user's role");
}
```

Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Take a look at this, it may work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55888823/guilds-highest-role-command

Answer (score 2):

`bot.user` is a `User` object, which does not contain any server-related data. What you're looking for is a `GuildMember` object.

In order to get the role for your bot, you need to fetch the member from the guild. This can be achieved with [`GuildMemberManager.resolve`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=resolve). You can use the guild's built-in property for this.

Your resulting code should look like this:

```js
if(message.mentions.members.first().roles.highest.position > message.guild.members.resolve(bot.user).roles.highest.position)
    return message.channel.send("My highest role is lower than the mentioned user's role");
```

Sometimes, `.resolve` will return `undefined`. In that case, you need to use `.fetch`. However, since you're getting the roles of your own bot, this shouldn't be much of an issue.

Comment: @WideIrenaKan1 You have to be a bit more specific for anyone to help. If you can edit your initial question with a stacktrace instead of the error message only, then someone will be able to help.